# Using timedelta to properly allign peaks on graph

Tags: python, datetime, scipy, numpy-ndarray, timedelta

I am using `scipy.signal` library to find the peaks of a time graph. I inputted the y values of my pandas series. And it gave me the location of the the peaks. Now i am trying to use the locations from the `find_peaks` function to return the position in time of the peaks. Here is my function:

```
def turn_peaks_to_time_series(df,t_interval):
    df_values = df['l'].values
    fig, ax1  = plt.subplots()
    
    x_of_peaks, _ = find_peaks(df_values, height=None)
    y_of_peaks = df_values[x_of_peaks]
    
    x_values_to_t_values = lambda x : timedelta(minutes=x) * t_interval
    time_initial = np.min(df.index)
    
    t_of_peaks = [ time_initial + x_values_to_t_values(int(i)) for i in x_of_peaks ] #source of issue
    
    ax1.plot(t_of_peaks, y_of_peaks, "rp",label='peak') #plot peaks on graph
    ax1.plot(df.index,df.l) # plot df line
    plt.show()
```

However, peaks are not properly aligning
[image: My graph]

I know the issue is with my `x_values_to_t_values` function. In addition, any suggesting to optimize my code are very welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i was trying to reinvent the wheel. The solution to my problem was extremely simple. Also I adjusted the code to be more general.

```
def turn_peaks_to_time_series(series):
    series_values = series.values
    series_index = series.index
    fig, ax1  = plt.subplots()
    
    x_of_peaks, _ = find_peaks(series_values, height=None)
    y_of_peaks = series_values[x_of_peaks]

    ax1.plot(series_index[x_of_peaks], y_of_peaks, "rp",label='peak') #plot peaks on graph
    ax1.plot(series_index,series_values) # plot df line
    plt.show()
```

[image: correct result]